# Read/Extract data from XML with Python

Tags: python, xml

I am trying to read/extract data from XML with Python using xml.etree.ElementTree.
Unfortunately, up to now, I didn't find how to do it. Most probably because I didn't understand how xml works.

The idea is to write the DocumentId number as a list

Here is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<RegisterSearch TotalResults="4">
  <SearchResults>
    <Document DocumentId="1348828088501913376">
      <DocumentNumber>001</DocumentNumber>
    </Document>
    <Document DocumentId="1348828088501881434">
      <DocumentNumber>001</DocumentNumber>
    </Document>
    <Document DocumentId="1348828088539553420">
      <DocumentNumber>010</DocumentNumber>
    </Document>
    <Document DocumentId="1348828088539570694">
      <DocumentNumber>010</DocumentNumber>
    </Document>
  </SearchResults>
</RegisterSearch>
```

And here is my Python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('documents.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for elem in root:
    if(elem.tag=='Document'):
        print elem.get('DocumentId')
```

This is what I try to achieve:

```
1348828088501913376
1348828088501881434
1348828088539553420
1348828088539570694
```

Actually, the code brings back nothing...

Thanks in advance for your suggestion.

Comment: Have you looked at any guides/tutorials/docs on this?

Comment: Yes I do, but I wasn't able to find the right way. The XML schema looks weird becuase I couldn't got it as I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate over the tags you are interested in:

```
for elem in root.iter(tag='Document'):
    print(elem.get('DocumentId'))
```

Your original solution would work with

```
for elem in root.iter():
    ...
```

---

v3.8: https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#finding-interesting-elements

v2.7: https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#finding-interesting-elements

Comment: I got an error as **AttributeError: 'Element' object has no attribute 'iner'**

Comment: @Stéphane That’s a typo, no?

Comment: @Alexander It works, sorry. I didn't a little mistake but it's solved. Thanks a lot for this.